# Can we enumerate the elements in an enum?

Tags: rust, enums

Suppose, I have the following `enum` type in Rust.

```
enum Expr {
    Null,
    Add(i32, i32),
    Sub(i32, i32),
    Mul(i32, i32),
    Div { dividend: i32, divisor: i32 },
    Val(i32),
}
```

I want to enumerate each element using a `for` loop.

Is it possible?

---

Elements can be enumerated using an extra array.

```
enum Expr {
    Null,
    Add(i32, i32),
    Sub(i32, i32),
    Mul(i32, i32),
    Div { dividend: i32, divisor: i32 },
    Val(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let expressions = [
        Expr::Null,
        Expr::Add(3, 4),
        Expr::Sub(10, 5),
        Expr::Mul(6, 2),
        Expr::Div { dividend: 15, divisor: 3 },
        Expr::Val(42),
    ];

    for expr in &expressions {
        match expr {
            Expr::Null => println!("Null expression"),
            Expr::Add(a, b) => println!("Addition: {} + {}", a, b),
            Expr::Sub(a, b) => println!("Subtraction: {} - {}", a, b),
            Expr::Mul(a, b) => println!("Multiplication: {} * {}", a, b),
            Expr::Div { dividend, divisor } => println!("Division: {} / {}", dividend, divisor),
            Expr::Val(value) => println!("Value: {}", value),
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to use an extra array.

Is that possible?

Comment: What's the extra array? `expressions`? It's not clear exactly what you mean by "enumerate each element".

Comment: If there were no array, what dictates that `Add` should have `3` and `4`?